# Flex based chat application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

HI all,

I have been asked to develop a generic chat client which can be used as a widget(with fb,twitter) which works fine with all XMPP supported applications.

I have decided to use flex along vit java.Could u pls suggest me sum useful sites.

I need more idea on the architecture on how the whole chat application works??

Also which server to use?? openfire or blaze DS?? what's the difference??

thanks:):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlazeDS would be a good start (although I've never used openfire).  I'd suggest downloading the turnkey install:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Downloads

Included within the turnkey package are sample applications which demonstrate publish/subscribe messaging (samples 6 and 7) which would be a good place to start.

The BlazeDS architecture (both client and server) is summarised on the Adobe docs pages:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=lcoverview_4.html